# Deleting multidimensional structs in C++ leads to access violations

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

I have a struct that has pointers to other structs.  As an example, my structs follow a pattern similar to this (although they're much more complicated).

```
typedef struct parent
{
    string name;
    int numOfKids;
    child* children;
}  parent

typedef struct child
{
    string name;
    details* information;
}  child

typedef struct details
{
    int age;
    string bestFriend;
}  details
```

To create a group of parents I do the following:

```
Parents * parents = new parents[numParents];
for(int i = 0; i< numParents; i++)
{
   parents[i].children = new children[parents[i].numOfKids];
   for (int j = 0; j < parents[i].numOfKids; j++)
   {
       parents[i].children[j].information = ( details* )malloc( sizeof( details ) );
       memset( parents[i].children[j].details, 0, sizeof( details ) );
   }
}
```

And later on I'm trying to clean up the memory like this:

```
void clearParents(parents** pParents, int numParents)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< numParents)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j< pParents[i]->numOfKids; j++)
        {
            free(pParents[i]->children[j].details);
        }

        delete [] pParents[i]->children
        delete( pParents[i])
     }
}
```

This clearParents function appears to work properly on the first loop through, but upon coming back to the inner loop, it crashes on

```
for (int j = 0; j < parents[i].numOfKids; j++)
```

with the error: 0xC0000005 Access Violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD4

I'm guessing this has something to do with me freeing/deleting memory in the array of parents while also trying to continue looping through it, but I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can give

Comment: omg why all the arrays and `new` and pointers? What design decision led to this?

Comment: Debug!! Start the debugger, and step through every line of your code, watch how variables change. Don't ask here before you've done with this!

Comment: Don't mix `new[]` with `delete`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sadly this is not my decision.  I'm actually using NvAPI and the structs represent one built by Nvidia.

If you want to see what my ACTUAL allocation looks like, you can see an example in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012589/2252761

Sadly Nvidia doesn't give any sort of documentation on how to go about freeing the memory once you're done, and I didn't want to put the whole struct here as it's intimidating if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: I still don't see how it requires all these nested dynamic allocations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit

That's what you have to do in order to use the Nvidia calls.  You create the struct, and do the nested dynamic allocations while making calls to Nvidia's API to fill them in with the actual data.  

Obviously it would be much better if I could just make a call and they'd return me an object, but that's now how it works sadly (and why I'm forced to do this extremely ugly memory deallocation)

Comment: @TrolliOlli: Why does the NVidia API care how you allocated the pointees? How does it even _know_?! Surely it'd be entirely trivial to write a wrapping class that allocated each object in a sensible manner, then populated the NVidia struct with pointers pointing to that data. Then no `new` or `delete` or pointers required whatsoever in your own interface......... It _is_ up to you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit

So you're saying I'd create a wrapper class using smarter allocations and then create the Nvidia struct and instead of using new or malloc, I'd just have it's member variables point to the new variables in my wrapper class?

I'm not able to see the internals of the Nvidia calls obviously, I just know that this way of allocation is the example that was given for how to use the calls, so I assumed it had to be done this way for the Nvidia calls to work

Comment: @TrolliOlli: Sure! I don't see any need for dynamic allocation here. I think you're putting too much into the "Nvidia is forcing me to do this and that and this" logic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll definitely look into this and see if I can get it to work.  Thanks!

Comment: a lot of your problems will just disappear if you use std::vector

Comment: @TrolliOlli Nvapi doesn't require any of this junk, you just don't know any better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got yourself confused with the double pointer `pParents`. Your pattern of deallocation does not match the pattern of allocation. I would guess that really you wanted something like this

```
void clearParents(parents* pParents, int numParents)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< numParents; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j< pParents[i].numOfKids; j++)
        {
            free(pParents[i].children[j].details);
        }
        delete[] pParents[i].children;
     }
     delete[] pParents;
}
```

Comment: Sadly I can't change the double pointer as this is just an example of my real code.  As I mentioned in a previous comment, I'm actually using Nvidia's API and these structs are simplified versions of the ones required by Nvidia calls.  With the double pointer still there, does the delete[] pParents[i] still work?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit
The method header in his example has "parents* pParents", in mine it has "parents** pParents".  

Maybe I'm confused, but it looks to me like he's removing the double pointer and other than the last delete, making all of the "->"s into "."s

If the design was up to me, I'd do it this way, but the double pointer is out of my hands

Comment: @TrolliOlli Right yes I see that now. Although I still don't understand why you think you "need" the double pointer. Just dereference it once on its way into the function..........

Comment: Even with a double pointer `delete[] pParents[i]` is wrong because you allocate once but delete `numParents` times. That's what I mean when I say the pattern of your deallocation does not match the pattern of allocation. If you have to have a double pointer then maybe you need `delete[] *pParents;`? And also `free((*pParents)[i].children[j].details);` and `delete[] (*pParents)[i].children;` but just guessing really.

Comment: @john

Oh okay that makes more sense! 

However, I still am getting the error (even if I take out that whole line), so it looks like the error is coming from one of the inner deletions of either children or children[j].details.

Comment: Yes, I edited the comment above to make some other suggestions for the inner deletions.

Comment: @john I made some changes to the rest of my program so I could use your original suggestion of getting rid of the double pointer and this appears to have fixed the problem.  So I believe that I would have needed to do something similar to your other suggestions if I wanted to keep the double pointer. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `new[]` with `delete`.  `pParents` was declared using `new[]` so you need to delete it at then end of the outer most for loop with `delete[]`.  You should not be trying to delete each element in the outer for loop.